# Migration from grails 2.1.1. to 2.3.10

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, upgrade

I am upgrading an application from grails 2.1.1 to grails 2.3.10. When I do grails compile, I have many "unable to resolve" messages for eg:

```
unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils

unable to resolve class net.sf.jmimemagic.Magic

unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GrailsUserDetailsService
```

I am suspecting that it is bcos of inability to access plugins. Or may be something has changed in Spring Security. I searched a bit to find out any guides to help me through. I appreciate any help to guide me on any read up material or suggestions that will help me upgrade it

Here is the BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
// configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version        forked compilation is required
//  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

// configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
// configure settings for the run-app JVM
run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
// configure settings for the run-war JVM
war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
// configure settings for the Console UI JVM
console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
// inherit Grails' default dependencies
inherits("global") {
    // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
    // excludes 'ehcache' 
}
log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or     'verbose'
checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not   advised and here for backwards compatibility

repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    mavenLocal()
    grailsCentral()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
    mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
    mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    mavenRepo "http://repo.spring.io/milestone/"
    mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core"

  }

   dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.27'
    //runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1102-jdbc4'
    test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0-grails-2.3"
  }

  plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.53"

    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.0.3"
    compile ':cache:1.1.2'

    //plugins for SpringSecurity
    compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"
    compile ":spring-security-acl:2.0-RC1"
    compile ":spring-security-ui:1.0-RC2"


    //plugins for the app
    compile ":webflow:2.0.0"    
    compile ":audit-logging:1.0.1"
    compile ":famfamfam:1.0.1"
    compile ":jquery-ui:1.10.3"
    compile ":searchable:0.6.8"
    compile ":ckeditor:4.4.1.0"
    compile ":rendering:1.0.0"
    compile ":gson:1.1.4"
    compile ":xmpp:0.1"
    compile ":latlongcalc:0.1"
    compile ":wslite:0.7.2.0"
    compile ":executor:0.3"
    compile ":google-visualization:0.7"


    //plugins for databases 
    compile ':mongodb:3.0.1'

    // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
    //runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.16" // or 
    runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.4"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
    runtime ":resources:1.2.7"



    // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
    //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0.1"
    //runtime ":cached-resources:1.1"
    //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"

    // An alternative to the default resources plugin is the asset-pipeline plugin
    //compile ":asset-pipeline:1.6.1"

    // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
    //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.5.5"
    //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.5.3"
    //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.5.0"
    //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.1"
   }
```

}

Comment: I hope you are also referring to [What's new in Grails 2.3](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/introduction.html#whatsNew23). Note that the default dependency resolution engine has changed to Aether.

Comment: yes, I updated the same as you can see in the BuildConfig.groovy. Is there anything else I need to do to turn off the earlier ivy dependency mechanism ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving your mavenRepo entries above the grailsPlugins() entry.

Comment: Got one step further Thanks @user3881763. Now I encounter         [context.GrailsContextLoader]Error initializing the application: org/hibernate/event/PreLoadEventListener 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/event/PreLoadEventListener
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
 ......

Comment: Do not recall a issue like the one above.  Are you switching from Hibernate 3 to 4?  You might try going back to Hibernate 3.

Comment: Actually, you are right. It was a conflict between Hibernate 3  in Webflow 2.0.8.1 and hibernate4 I defined in dependencies.